# Assembly 64 bit GAS, count odd and negative numbers

Tags: assembly, x86

I would appreciate some help with the code given below. The code is supposed to take a reference for a table, the number of objects and count how many there are negative values and odd values. 
Then it should send the number of negative values to one table in the memory and the number of odd values to the other table in the memory.
I tried comparing to zero, I tried finding the last bit, I tried xor of the registry, nothing works. It is important that all the values are long long types.

```
.type max_1_ind, @function
.global max_1_ind

max_1_ind:
    movq    %rdi, %r8         # object table address from rdi to r8
    xor     %r11, %r11
    xor     %r12, %r12
    movq    %rcx, %r14        # rcx is needed for the loop
    movq    %rsi, %rcx        # number of objects for the loop counter
    xor     %r15, %r15
loop:
    movq    (%r8), %r15
    and     $1, %r15        
    jc      increase
continue:
    movq     (%r8), %r15
    test     %r15, %r15
    jne      increase2            
continue2:
    inc      %r8                 
    dec      %rcx
    cmpq     $0, %rcx
    jne      loop

    movq     %r11, (%rdx)
    movq     %r14, %rcx
    movq     %r12, (%rcx)

finish:
    xor      %rax, %rax
    ret

increase:
    inc      %r11                
    jmp      continue
increase2:
    inc      %r12                
    jmp      continue2
```

And the "c" program that calls this function

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

extern long long max_1_ind(long long *tab, long long n, long long *even_cnt, long long *neg_cnt);

int main(void) {
  long long tab[4] = {6, 2, -20, 3};
  long long count = 4;
  long long even_cnt[1] = {0};
  long long neg_cnt[1] = {0};
  max_1_ind(tab, count, even_cnt, neg_cnt);
  printf("Result: %lld, %lld\n", *even_cnt, *neg_cnt);
  return 0; 
}
```

Comment: When you do `inc %r8` how much does that add to r8? And how wide are long long values?

Comment: You should step through the assembly code in a debugger. you'd be able to see what is in the registers as you step through the code.

Comment: I mention r8 because i suspect it was the root of all your original problems. There are still issues with your branch instructions. Title of your question says to find the odd count but your variable names suggest you are trying to find an even count.

Comment: `js` can be used to branch based on the sign and if you `and` something with 1 then it is an even number if the result is 0 so a `jnz` (jump not zero) seems more appropriate.if you are trying to figure out if it is odd.

Comment: And one other consideration you should be concerned about is the calling convention ([64-bit System V ABI](http://www.x86-64.org/documentation/abi.pdf) in your case) and which registers have to be preserved by the function (if they are modified). RBX, R12 to R15 RBP have to be preserved (see figure 3.4 at that link). In your case you destroy R12, R14, and R15 but don't preserve them. this can cause problems for the _C_ code that calls your function if it was using those registers.

Comment: "nothing works" is not an error description. Please tell us what your program does and what you expect it to do instead.

Comment: FUZxxi, the code works now, I made a mistake with inc instead of add $8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your insightful answer. Yes, I made a mistake with inc. Now the code works correctly.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

extern long long max_1_ind(long long *tab, long long n, long long *even_cnt, long long *neg_cnt);

int m(long long * tab, long long n, long long *even_cnt, long long *neg_cnt){
        int counter = n;
    while(counter>-1){
            //printf("%lld \n",tab[counter]);
        if(tab[counter]<0){
            neg_cnt[0]++;
        }
                if ((tab[counter] & 1) ==0){
            even_cnt[0]++;
        }
        counter--;
    }
        return 0;
}

int main(void) {
  long long tab[4] = {6, 40, -20, -3};
  long long count = 4;
  long long even_cnt[1] = {0};
  long long neg_cnt[1] = {0};
  max_1_ind(tab, count, even_cnt, neg_cnt);
  printf("Wynik Asembler: %lld, %lld\n", *even_cnt, *neg_cnt);
  return 0;
}
```

And assembly code:

```
.type max_1_ind, @function
#long long max_1_ind(long long *tab, long long n, long long *even_cnt, long long *neg_cnt);
.global max_1_ind

                # %rdi, %rsi, %rdx, %rcx, %r8 and %r9


max_1_ind:
    movq    %rdi, %r8         
        xor     %r11, %r11
        xor     %r12, %r12
        movq    %rsi, %rcx        
        xor     %r15, %r15

loop:
        movq    (%r8), %r15
        andq    $1, %r15        
        jz      increase

continue:
        movq     (%r8), %r15
        testq    %r15, %r15
        js       increase2  

continue2:
        addq     $8, %r8                 
        dec      %rcx
        cmpq     $0, %rcx
        jne      loop

        movq     %r11, (%rdx)
        movq     %r14, %rcx
        movq     %r12, (%rcx)

finish:
        xor      %rax, %rax
        ret

increase:
        inc      %r11                
        jmp      continue

increase2:
        inc      %r12                
        jmp      continue2
```